openssl_decrypt(): IV passed is 29 bytes long which is longer than the 16 expected by selected cipher, truncating
I get the error message on the title when I try to login to some accounts from the admin side.
This is the code:
private function decryptString($string){

    $ciphering = "AES-128-CTR";  
    $options = 0; 
    $decryption_iv = '4F109F987HJ91597CCB4AF4D6'; 
    $decryption_key = "(Ct:>)xByg68>In&l1P!;6dhd>llD-zel.9aSC+986cn;j8,.J"; 
    $decryption = openssl_decrypt($string, $ciphering, 
                $decryption_key, $options, $decryption_iv); 
    return $decryption;
}

the log says the error is in the "$decryption = openssl_decrypt" line
tried changing to 256-ctr but it does not do anything. Cant think of anything else and changing the aes mode is not an option.

This is probably due to the data. In addition to the IV (see answer), the key also has the wrong size. AES uses 16, 24 or 32 bytes key, yours has 50 bytes. PHP/OpenSSL corrects this implicitly by only using the first 16 bytes (for AES-128-CTR), but the 50 bytes key could still be an indication for invalid/corrupted data. Also keep in mind that PHP/OpenSSL Base64 decodes for $options = 0 on decryption. Thus, describe how the data was encrypted, or even better post the code, and post complete sample data that you want to decrypt (this includes ciphertext and plaintext next to key and IV).

As you can see from the docs, iv is a non-NULL initialization vector. It has the type of String. Your iv is:
$decryption_iv = '4F109F987HJ91597CCB4AF4D6';

which is too long for your algo, which is
$ciphering = "AES-128-CTR";

The iv length should be of 16 bytes for your algo, see https://www.baeldung.com/java-invalidalgorithmparameter-exception
So you will either need a new iv, or change your algo, depending on what suits your needs better.
EDIT (Inspired from Dave Thompson in the chat):

For encryption it's enough to use any key and IV that satisfies the requirements of your cipher (which here is really algorithm PLUS mode, in spite of PHP's and OpenSSL's sometimes suboptimal naming); for decryption not only must the key and IV be valid for the cipher, but all three must be (exactly) the same as were used for the specific encryption you want to decrypt


For encryption it's enough to use any key and IV that satisfies the requirements of your cipher (which here is really algorithm PLUS mode, in spite of PHP's and OpenSSL's sometimes suboptimal naming); for decryption not only must the key and IV be valid for the cipher, but all three must be (exactly) the same as were used for the specific encryption you want to decrypt (info not given in the Q).

@dave_thompson_085 thanks for your comment, I have edited the answer accordingly.
